# Locate source code from pip install packages in Ubuntu

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, pip, package

I have installed some packages with pip in Ubuntu. However, I want to change some part of the installed code from those packages. In windows is easy to do so, from Pycharm using provided links. How can I locate the source code from the packages and make changes? My import code:

```
from metric_learn import LSML_Supervised
```

Comment: You can import the package and then run `package.__file__` to get the location.

Comment: Answerers assumed a Python 3 answer was required, because the OP did not mention version. I've edited the tags to clarify that it was essentially a 2.7 question, and added this comment to explain why the answers are mostly Python 3.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Generally speaking, modules and packages have a `__file__` attribute that you can use to find out where they were loaded from:

```
>>> import jinja2
>>> jinja2.__file__
'/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/felix_backend/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/__init__.py'
```

**EDIT Nov 20 '20** The original answer might have been more helpful had it mentioned that `pip` normally installs packages in the (sometimes virtual) environment's `site-packages` directory, but that the `-e` option can be used to install a module or package in so-called *editable* mode from a directory or URL. From `pip install --help`:

```
  -e, --editable <path/url>   Install a project in editable mode (i.e.
                              setuptools "develop mode") from a local project
                              path or a VCS url.
```

This is commonly used by cloning a git repository (most open source software can be accessed in this way from Github or similar sources) and then installing it with `pip install -e`. The environment's interpreter will use the code from the given directory, which are linked in rather than being copied into the environment's `site-packages` directory.

The import system is quite complex, but if a module's `__file__` attribute doesn't answer your questions, consult the documentation on [import-related module attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#import-related-module-attributes).

**EDIT Mar 27 '22** For packages, the issue is somewhat more complex. If an imported object has a `__path__` attribute then it is a package, and `__path__` is a (possible empty) iterable of strings. This allows for [*namespace packages*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#namespace-packages), whose contents can be installed incrementally and from different directories.

To assist in understanding all this, you can create a simple package by creating a directory and, in that, creating an empty `module.py` file and a `package` subdirectory containing only an empty `__init__.py`. I did that, and ran the following script.

```
sholden@fathead-2 pkgtest % python
Python 3.9.10 (main, Jan 15 2022, 11:48:00)
[Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import module, package
>>> module.__file__
'/private/tmp/pkgtest/module.py'
>>> package.__path__
['/private/tmp/pkgtest/package']
```

Here's what the filestore looked like after execution - also showing how the interpreter has created `.pyc` files for both the module and the package.

```
sholden@fathead-2 pkgtest % tree $(pwd)
/tmp/pkgtest
├── __pycache__
│   └── module.cpython-39.pyc
├── module.py
└── package
    ├── __init__.py
    └── __pycache__
        └── __init__.cpython-39.pyc

3 directories, 4 files
```

Comment: My code is from metric_learn import LSML_Supervised. When I am trying to  print LSML_Supervised i got <class 'metric_learn.lsml.LSML_Supervised'>

Comment: __file__ attribute does not work for me: AttributeError: type object 'LSML_Supervised' has no attribute '__file__'

Comment: such a great feature! i wish all languages made it these easy to work on open source code.

Answer (score 4):

`site-packages` is the target directory of manually built python packages. When you build and install python packages from source (using distutils, probably by executing `python setup.py install`), you will find the installed modules in site-pacakges by default.

```
>>> import site; site.getsitepackages()
['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
```

---

If you really doubt default location then,

```
>>> import django
>>> print django.__path__
['/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django']
```

Comment: My code is the following from metric_learn import LSML_Supervised. Not sure what should i have for __path__

Comment: Seems that __path__ attribute does not exist in python2.7